# What type should I use to define buffer size in interface?

Tags: c++, interface

My module will be used in x86 and x64 envrionment. I have a header file including a exported function with the following signature.

```
HRESULT GetObject(DWORD key, void* pValue, MY_SIZE_T  cbSize);
```

What type should I use for the type **MY_SIZE_T**.

1. Use the `std::size_t` to describe the size of object pointed by pValue. But the std::size_t differs in x86 and x64 platform. I am not sure it is fine in the interface level.
2. Use the `DWORD` which has fixed width. But DWORD may not be big enough in x64 platform. Although it is rare to have a structure over 2^32 bytes.

Comment: Consider using `uint64_t`, though it may be not defined on some platforms

Comment: Are you planning to compile this code once and use the same *binary code* on both platforms? I would image that you'd run into a ton of other problems before the size of `size_t` becomes an issue.

Comment: @KerrekSB Nope. I will compile the code in two platforms one for x86, one for x64.

Comment: @ChenOT: Then use `std::size_t`; the fact that its range is platform-dependent shouldn't matter. You get whatever your platform supports. Just like you have less address space with 32-bit. Different platforms are different; "portable" doesn't mean "identical", it means "makes sense on different platforms". Your 32-bit module will simply not support large structures.

Comment: @KerrekSB Thanks. Everything in interface level becomes different, so I want to be careful the exported types.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That depends on what `cbSize` is supposed to contain. If it's actually the size of the object pointed to by `pValue` then `std::size_t` is definitely the correct choice.

`std::size_t` is guaranteed to exist, and guaranteed to be large enough to hold the size of an object. If you have 64-bit pointers it will have at least 64-bits and if you've got 32-bit pointers then it will (probably) be only 32 bits.

Note that binary compatibility is probably not a concern here. If you have a 32-bit system and complile for that you can't link it with code compiled for 64-bit system anyway. It should be no problem that the size of the third argument differs (and if it did you would have problem with the pointer anyway).